# How to create a materialized view with union(or union all) and joins

Tags: oracle, union-all, materialized-views

For performance needs I want to create a materialized view on commit refresh option using the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE DEVDV 
(DEVDV_ID INTEGER PRIMARY kEY, 
DEVDV_SRC_DVISE_ID INTEGER, 
DEVDV_CIB_DVISE_ID INTEGER);


CREATE TABLE CONDV 
(CONDV_ID INtEgEr PRiMARY KEY, 
CONDV_DEVDV_iD INTEGER, 
CONDV_TX NUMbeR, 
CONDV_DATE_DEB datE, 
CONDV_DATE_FIN DATE);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON DEVDV WITH ROWID;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON CONDV WITH ROWID;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DEVDV_TYP_2
REFRESH FAST
ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT DEVDV.ROWID CROWID,
       CONDV.ROWID DROWID,
       DEVDV_ID,
       1 AS MARKER,
       DEVDV_SRC_DVISE_ID,
       DEVDV_CIB_DVISE_ID,
       CONDV_TX, 
       CONDV_DATE_DEB,
       CONDV_DATE_FIN
FROM
    DEVDV INNER JOIN CONDV ON DEVDV_ID = CONDV_DEVDV_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT DEVDV.ROWID CROWID,
       CONDV.ROWID DROW_ID,
       DEVDV_ID,
       2 AS MARKER,
       DEVDV_CIB_DVISE_ID,
       DEVDV_SRC_DVISE_ID,
       1/CONDV_TX, 
       CONDV_DATE_DEB,
       CONDV_DATE_FIN
FROM
    DEVDV INNER JOIN CONDV ON DEVDV_ID = CONDV_DEVDV_ID;
```

Oracle says that it's a complex query and it doesn't meet the fast refresh requirements,

Could you please tell me which rule I've broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but - for materialized views in oracle - you have to use old syntax for joins. So put all tables in FROM separating them with commas, and join condition put in where clause (use "(+)" for outer joins).

That works for me:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DEVDV_TYP_2
REFRESH FAST
ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT DEVDV.ROWID CROWID,
       CONDV.ROWID DROWID,
       DEVDV_ID,
       1 AS MARKER,
       DEVDV_SRC_DVISE_ID,
       DEVDV_CIB_DVISE_ID,
       CONDV_TX, 
       CONDV_DATE_DEB,
       CONDV_DATE_FIN
FROM
    DEVDV, CONDV
WHERE DEVDV_ID = CONDV_DEVDV_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT DEVDV.ROWID CROWID,
       CONDV.ROWID DROW_ID,
       DEVDV_ID,
       2 AS MARKER,
       DEVDV_CIB_DVISE_ID,
       DEVDV_SRC_DVISE_ID,
       1/CONDV_TX, 
       CONDV_DATE_DEB,
       CONDV_DATE_FIN
FROM
    DEVDV, CONDV 
WHERE DEVDV_ID = CONDV_DEVDV_ID;

Materialized view MV_DEVDV_TYP_2 created.
```